# document ready call sql function

Tags: jquery, highcharts

any can help me how to call sql function from document ready the problem i have im working with Highcharts the get all stats so i made a box it said stats of last 3 day , 7day , 30days or ...
the problem how the call the sql from the val

```
                        <select id="days" name="selectbasic" class="form-control" style="height:35px;">
                            <option value="3" selected>Last 3 days</option>
                            <option value="7" >Last 7 Days</option>
                            <option value="14" >Last 14 Days</option>
                            <option value="30" >Last 30 Days</option>
                            <option value="-1" >All History</option>
                        </select>
```

when i hit the button the call is here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#update-button').click(function () {
      haw the call sql from here plz ??????       $('#days').val();
    });
});
```

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe jquery can make sql requests directly, the simple answer is, do an ajax get or post request, and create a php page which handles the sql query.

This guide should probably be enough for what you are asking, assuming you are using mysql, otherwise you will need to change the php page appropriately.

https://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/ajax-add-retrieve-mysql-records-using-jquery-php/

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript is on client(browser) and mysql is on server. There is no way you will be able to run sql query directly. Ideal solution will be to call a service/url with the filters/values that will be used in where clause of yur mysql query and return the response after executing sql. Use the response in plotting your chart.

Comment: ty i get fixed from the exemple site hi posted alden